# Cannot Redeclare the Function

Tags: php

My File Structure is as follows.

1. Script A --> includes Script C ( A logger Script ) and Script B.
2. Script B --> includes Script C ( A logger Script )
3. Script C --> logger Script. Contains a couple of constant definitions and Logging functions.

So, If I include Script C in both Script A and B, I get the error function redeclared.

If I do not include it in Script B, I get Undefined Function Error.

Script B contains some other function definitions which are to be used by Script A.

I run Script A, It should start logging... Call a function from Script B which in turns starts logging in a different logger instance.

I have tried include_once and require_once. But to no avail. They both gave me the same results as using include or require.

Edit 1: I did not post the code, as it is very long and I need to check if I am missing some basic concepts first.

Comment: Are all your file declarations at the top? So that in theory it would look like require C; require B; require C;?

Comment: what is the `Exact` error you are receiving.

Comment: if you switched to the `_once()` alternatives, and still get the error, then you've got the function defined twice in those files. e.g. file a: `function foo() { ...}` and file b: `function foo() { ... }`

Comment: You might want to encapsulate C into a class and check how autoloading works: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: The error message about the redeclaration should give the file and line number where it was previously declared.

Comment: The exact error is: "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare initializeLogger() (previously declared in ... "

Comment: @Barmar, It is pointing to Script C.

Comment: Is that "previously declared" line the same or different from where the error is occurring?

Comment: @MarcB, No. I just grepped the entire directory for declarations. It is the only definition.

Comment: @amflare, yes I include all my dependencies at the very Begining. Script A has include Script B and include Script C, Script B has include Script C before any code begins.

Comment: `declared in ...` ... in what you need to post the `whole` error not parts

Comment: You're sure you're including the same Script C in both places, not a copy? Check the full pathname in the error message.

Comment: got it. @amflare, thanks for pointing it out. I switched the order. I included Script C first and Script B next. Then I removed it from Script B. Its working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was the order in which I included the files.

I messed up the include order whereby it is including twice when compiling Script A. I fixed it by changing the order of including statements in Script A and removing the include from Script B

Answer (score 1):

Use `require_once` or `include_once` to avoid redaclaration of functions

```
require_once 'scriptC.php';
require_once 'scriptB.php';
```

or

```
include_once 'scriptC.php';
include_once 'scriptB.php';
```

This will ensure that each of your includes does only get loaded once.

Comment: The question says that he tried that and it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap functions like so

```
if ( ! function_exists('foo'))
{
  function foo($bar)
  { 
    ... 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats just a workaround. I do not want to do that for every function